# Help finding the type of distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, distribution-identification

I am doing a question which involves the following probability density function
$$f(x;\mu,\lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^{3}}} exp\bigg(\frac{-\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x}\bigg), x>0, \lambda,\mu>0$$
my question is what type of distribution is this? It slightly resembles the normal distributions but not quite.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: This is known as the [Wald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution -- also called Inverse Gaussian.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from [@knrumsey's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/126931/knrumsey) comment so an answer will show up in the answers:

> This is known as the [Wald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution -- also called Inverse Gaussian